# Strange Nullpointer with Spanned

Tags: android

I have some objects with a Spanned attribute. These are filled with HTML code including images. 
On a button click I display the Spanned content in a TextView.
SOMETIMES (and I cannot reproduce this) I get this exception:

`11-07 23:26:16.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23715): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 23:26:16.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23715):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.length(SpannableStringBuilder.java:126)
11-07 23:26:16.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23715):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2631)
11-07 23:26:16.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23715):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)
11-07 23:26:16.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23715):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)
11-07 23:26:16.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23715):    at [...]`

In the following second line, the exception is thrown (so the Spanned isnt null!):

```
if(hasSpanned){
        tv.setText(ans.getTxtS());  
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `tv` is null or `ans` is null. You can write a little test to figure out which one it is by inserting the following code before your if statment:

```
if(tv == null){
   Log.e("MyError", "Tv was null");
}

if(ans == null){
  Log.e("myError", "ans was null");
}
```

When you figure our which one it is, go through your code and check to make sure you've initialized them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kurtis! But I get the hasSpanned before with : boolean hasSpanned = (ans.getTxtS()==null) ? false : true; The tv isnt null, too :-(

Comment: Okay the ans.getTxtS() didnt throw a NullPointer, but the ans shows a com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method. when I watch it in debug mode. Strange thing both. Sometimes it works..